# Hypothetically, could someone other than the Cardano Foundation or IO publish an application back end first?

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications, pab

The Plutus Application Backend remains to be published.

Could someone else put one up first?

What would happen?

Answer (score 1):

There would simply be two competing libraries and users could simply choose which one they prefer.